# How to handle RTP session in Xamarin forms for Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, sip, rtp

I am trying make an application that will allow a registered client to make an audio call to another registered client using Wi-Fi(It doesn't require internet).

I was able to successfully register and make call using SIP.

After the call is picked up, I don't know how to handle the RTP stream and connect it with the microphone and speaker of the phone(Android and IOS) to perform normal calling functionality.

I am using Xamarin and SIP Sorcery library. I am new to Xamarin and mobile application development.

Below is a part of code to explain myself a little better:

```
    async Task Call()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start of Calling section");

        rtpSession = new RTPMediaSession((int)SDPMediaFormatsEnum.PCMU, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

        // May be somthing like this to connect audio devices to RTP session.
        //get microphone
        //get speaker
        //ConnectAudioDevicesToRtp(rtpSession, microphone, speaker);

        // Place the call and wait for the result.
        bool callResult = await userAgent.Call(DESTINATION, ssid, userName, registerPassword, domainHost, rtpSession);

        if (callResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call attempt successful. Start talking");
            //I am reaching to this point and need help with how to move forward from here to support audio calling functionality for both Android and IOS
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call attempt failed.");
        }

    }
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation from SIP Sorcery, there I found only an example for windows (https://sipsorcery.github.io/sipsorcery/articles/sipuseragent.html),  but not for ios or android.

Here is the description from SIP Sorcery for cross platform (https://sipsorcery.github.io/sipsorcery/). I think you need the SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg library

Comment: I have turned this into what might be accepted as a partial answer to an otherwise not yet fully answered question. Please read [answer] and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and [tour].